# Camel SFTP file transfer, increasing performance

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel SFTP component in my project, having a use case like send up to 1000 (<50 KB) files to a remote FTP server every second, but our code seems struggling to do that overtime. We are keeping FTP connection open for reuse.

Is there any way in which we can improve the file transfer performance by opening multiple connections to the same host, something like `maxConnectionsPerHost`, `maxTotalConnections` ?

Answer (score 1):

FTP/SFTP producer do support multiple concurrent connection to same target with same setup. You can achieve this by create multiple routes point to same target.

For example, create 10 folders and have 10 routes collect from each folder and send to same target. Then have a route to collect file/message from source and send to the 10 folders evenly.

---

Other than using concurrent FTP/SFTP connection, probably switch to other protocol  (e.g. HTTP, JMS) that are naturally support concurrent multiple connection in high speed is a better choice.